# Not getting user details on google signin in JS

Tags: javascript, google-signin

I am using the new way of google login mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/migration). However I am getting only the *client_id*, *cliendId*, *credential*(token), and *select_by: "btn"* as response. I would also like to get details such as user email in response, as we need it to verify the email. Given below is the HTML code I'm using, and the call back function:

```
<div id="g_id_onload"
     data-client_id="MY_CLIENT_ID"
     data-callback="handleCredentialResponse"         
</div>
<div class="g_id_signin" data-type="standard"></div>
```

The callback is simply:

```
function handleCredentialResponse(data){
    console.log(data)
}
```

Currently the login page opens up in a new tab, I would like to get it as a popup. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Got answer to my first question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73211053/why-decodejwtresponse-is-not-defined-at-nn-handlecredentialresponse-as-callback

However how do I open the google login as popup on the same page?